# yo webapp command freezes (windows 7)

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, yeoman

I had no trouble running `yo webapp` in Ubuntu terminal. But when I run it in windows it freezes at this point
[image]

**Question:** How do I fix it, so that it won't freeze at the point shown in the picture?

---

**PS:** Just to put all output here tried running `yo webapp > output.txt` but it stops at the first question.

```
     _-----_
    |       |
    |--(o)--|   .--------------------------.
   `---------´  |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
    ( _´U`_ )   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    /___A___\   '__________________________'
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

Out of the box I include HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery, and a Gruntfile.js to build your app.
[[32m?[39m] What more would you like? (Press <space> to select)
[36m>[39m[32m[X][39m Bootstrap
 [ ] Sass
 [ ] Modernizr[?25lTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Comment: Having the same problem on Mac

Comment: do you have git available in your terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that git bin directory was not included in Windows' PATH variable. First tried running bower manually and it said `git is not recognized...`.

**Solution.** `Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > PATH` added git bin here separated by `;`. In my case git bin directory was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`.

---

**PS:** Just in case someone runs into same problem, I won't delete the question :D

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be multiple solutions.

But a quick and simple solution in case it already happened and is hanging the following worked for me.
Just type "n" and then hit "enter".

Explanation: it seems that there is a question and a prompt waiting for an answer (maybe something to do with anonymous reporting on SASS usage, I can't recall). Once you hit "n" or "y" (is up to you) and then "enter" it should continue and finish. You can see the question and the answer if you scroll back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows 7 running the ember generator on npm. It stopped at the same place on cmd as in the screen shot above. Typing "n" and hitting "enter" allowed the generator to finish.